# I want to define a hover color in the style sheet

Tags: navigation, theming

I designed a page with the corporateclean theme on http://www.athleticedgefitness.com/. I used nice menus for the drop down. Now I would like to color all my links #E3007B on hover, but I'm not exactly sure how I can get this accomplished. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this in the css of your subtheme ("styles.css" i think):

a:hover, li:hover {color:#E3007B !important;}

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! I've never seen the important keyword - I have to look that up! Thanks! :)